# Firefox link redirection issue using selenium

Tags: scala, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have an automation service I build and before you run the automation you give it a link so when you start the automation you get first redirect to this link.

On my machine you get redirected perfectly, but on a friend machine the Firefox browser is opened and thats it.

does anyone know what might be the issue?

here is the class that responsible for this:

```
case class csvUploadData(clientUrl: String)
  val csvUploadForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "clientUrl" -> nonEmptyText)(csvUploadData.apply)(csvUploadData.unapply))

  def uploadCSV = Action.async(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request =>
    csvUploadForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => {
        Future {
          Redirect(routes.Application.index).flashing(
            "error" -> formWithErrors.error("clientUrl").get.message)
        }
      },
      userData => {
        request.body.file("csvFile").fold(Future {
          Redirect(routes.Application.index).flashing(
            "error" -> "Missing CSV file").withSession(request.session)
        }) { formFile =>
          import java.io.File
          val filename = formFile.filename
          Future {
            val file = formFile.ref.file
            val purchaseInfos = purchaseDS(file)

            val t = Try {
              val driver: WebDriver = new FirefoxDriver
              val actions: ActionsHMRC = new ActionsHMRC(driver, userData.clientUrl)

              val results = actions.insertData(purchaseInfos)
              results.filter(_._2.isFailure)
            }
            t match {
              case Success(failures) =>
                val failedMsg = if (failures.nonEmpty)
                  failures.map{case (pi, err) => s"${pi.invoiceNumber} -> ${err}}"}.mkString("The following rows failed: [\n","\n","\n\n\n]")
                else ""
                Redirect(routes.Application.index).flashing(
                "success" -> s"The file '$filename' automation successfuly.\n$failedMsg")
              case Failure(e) =>
                println(e)
                Redirect(routes.Application.index).flashing (
                "error" -> s"The file '$filename' automation failed.")
            }
          }
        }
      })
  }
}
```

I have ver 42.0 and he have 43.0.4

Comment: Is selenium JAR version is same in both machines? latest jars 2.50.1 supports both and also in friend machine he manually able to navigate that link?

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: its a whole proj, which part of the code do you want to see?

Comment: The code which is not working

Comment: @MosamMehta done, added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's happening because the new issue occurs with latest update of Mozilla firefox.

It's happening with me too.

To overcome from this issue you need to setPreference as `xpinstall.signatures.required", false` to firefox Profile and then pass it to driver object

```
firefoxProfile.setPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required", false);
```

Below code is working fine for old selenium jars.

```
static WebDriver driver=null;
public static void main(String[] args) {
final FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.setPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required", false);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
driver.get("https://www.google.de/");
```

Thanks it really helps but one change `FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile)` is not valid. instead FirefoxOptions as below:

```
final FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.setPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required", false);
FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.setProfile(firefoxProfile);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
```

Comment: Welcome ... It's my pleasure :)

Comment: @Katta Nagarjuna - Yes that is because I have posted that answer in Feb 2 16 and then FirefoxProfile was valid.. in new jar FirefoxProfile  is deprecated and so now we need to use firefoxOptions. Thanks for updating the answer. really appreciated